# Display Bundle Products in Category Listing When Bundle Options Not Set

Tags: bundled-product

I create new bundle product in magento without any bundle option selection.
I assign category,store and inventory same as simple product.
I check that product not display in category products listing.
If I create bundle option than it's display there.
I want to display all bundle products in category listing even if bundle option not set because of display product information in website.

Answer (score 2):

A bundle without options does not make sense, it's incomplete.

If you need a placeholder product that is not purchasable, for product information, it could be a simple product that's out of stock or gets a special attribute which you check in your template to hide price and "add to cart" button.

If for some reason it must be a bundle, you could create one option with one dummy simple product that's out of stock.